# jUnit:NPE on private member initialization

Tags: java, junit, initialization, field, jmockit

Have `jUnit` test, which initializes my bean:

```
ShowProducts sp = new ShowProducts();
```

got `NullPointerException` on following line in ShowProducts.java:

```
    private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
                .getLocale();

...
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void localize() {
        String localeParam = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("lang");
        locale = new Locale(localeParam);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }
```

How to initialize properly this field in test?

**EDIT:**

**faces-config:**

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>ua</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>msg</base-name>
        <var>m</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

**.xhtml:**

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{showProducts.localize}" includeViewParams="true"
                       rendered="#{showProducts.language=='ua'}">
            #{m.rus}.
            <f:param name="lang" value="ru"/>
        </h:commandLink>
        <h:commandLink action="#{showProducts.localize}" includeViewParams="true"
                       rendered="#{showProducts.language=='ru'}">
            #{m.ukr}.
            <f:param name="lang" value="ua"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently your JSF FacesContext is not configured properly (I do no know much about faces, but I assume that setting them up and running in jUnit test is pretty complicated). However, there is help underway - use mocking.

In your test case, you like to assure that:
   - ShowProducts retrieves proper locale out of faces context / view root
   - does  other things properly.

I recommend you to use jmockit.  Your test case would become  something like:

```
 @Test
 public void testShowProducts(@Cascading final FacesContext facesContext) {
        final Locale locale = new Locale(...)
        new Expectations() {
           {
              FacesContext.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
              returns(locale);
           }


        };
       ShowProducts sp = new ShowProducts();

       ...  do your assertions other stuff there
 }
```

This techuique is applicable to lot of contextes and simplifies test code greatly.

Comment: Passing in a complete FacesContext when all you need is a Locale seems like overkill.

Comment: Actually this is not a context but  magical mock up - so no overkill there.

Comment: Had to try it myself to see the benefit. Thanks for recommending jmockit.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing static methods makes writing tests hard.

Either pass the Locale with the constructor or use a setter.

The easiest change would be to add a second constructor with a Locale as parameter and use it for the unittest. The default constructor then initializes the field from the FacesContext.

Towards a cleaner design you should extract a `Localizer` where you handle all the localization, so to separate then `ShowProducts` which doesn't need the `FacesContext` from the `Localizer` which does.

The Localizer would be something like:

```
public class Localizer {
    public void localize() {
        String localeParam = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("lang");
        locale = new Locale(localeParam);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

This has nothing to do with `ShowProducts`. Not sure what you need `getLanguge()` for.

Comment: CKuck,thank you for hint.So it looks like my class is bad-testable and it's better to redesign it?

Comment: Bad testability is sure sign  of  bad design -  so it is best to redesign it (singleton is evil pattern,   and shall be avoided if possible).  But if you can not  , you can mock up  faces easily. ( see my answer )

Comment: Konstantin,thank you for help.So do you assume refactor of `locale` field initialization?I don't know is it possible,as far I need call `getLanguage()`,which relies on locale,and locale is set in faces-config.See,please, EDIT section in my post.

Comment: In `localize()` you are using the FacesContext again to get the `ExternalContext`. It would be a much cleaner design if all those information were passed in. -- added a suggestion for a improved design to my answer.

Comment: Looks like in I should initialize locale in `getLanguage()` also,in order not to get NPE,if i remove locale initialization as private member,isn't it?

Comment: CKuck , do you assume under `Localizer` the `locale` field?

Comment: Reread your code again... all `localize()` does shouldn't be in a class like `ShowProducts` as it only plays with the `FacesContext` and doesn't really interact with the class itself.

Comment: If you need the language for something else, you should have a field for that and mock that if necessary.

Comment: There is relatively ( about 10 Years old ) new concept of dependency injection ( aka Hollywood pattern - do not call us we call you) - main idea is that it's not a business of your localizer  where locale comes from. It would be provided by DI container ( spring , pico, guice... ) - it just  has to specofy need in this locale by means of property setter or constructor parameter ( I prefer constructor injectsion)